# Import Error for gensim in spyder(python)

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to `import gensim` in spyder (Python). I have already installed the package through `cmd`. Here is the code I have come up with:

```
import gensim
from gensim import corpora,models
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]
ldamodel = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus, num_topics=3, id2word = dictionary, passes=20)
```

Problem is it's showing the error

```
ImportError: No module named gensim
```

Comment: Did it work in terminal/command prompt? Are you sure it is installed properly

Comment: yes it's  working in cmd but gives warning  ----   warnings.warn("detected Windows; aliasing chunkize to chunkize_serial")

Comment: You could move the package into the same directory as the program